# TypeScript: Declare an object then assign variables in certain conditions

Tags: typescript

I'd like to declare an object, then assign it different values depending on different conditions. Why does this code snippet give the error
"Variable 'answer' is used before being assigned."

```
let answer: {
  diff: number | undefined,
  value: number | undefined,
}


if(answer.diff === undefined) {
  console.log('not defined')
}
```

Comment: Because you've not assigned anything to it yet you try to use it. The error is exact, clear, and correct.

Comment: So if it is unassigned, that isn't the same as undefined?

Comment: Nothing assigned means the value is `undefined`. But the compiler rightly tells you that you're trying to use the variable before giving it any real value.Otherwise `answer.diff` would thrown an error since `answer = undefined` and you cannot read a property from `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) said, the error is clear, just assign an initial value for the object and it should work now.

```
let answer: {
  diff: number | undefined,
  value: number | undefined,
} = {diff: undefined, value: undefined}
```